# Laurent series confusion

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

[image]

I've split it up into partial fractions and got $1/z$ - $2/(z-1)$ + $1/(z-2)$ but I'm unsure sure what to do now.

I think I have done part $(i)$. I get

$$z^{-1} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (2-(1/2^{n+1})z^n)$$

What do I do with the $z^{-1}$?  How do I get it into the summation?

For part $(ii)$ I get ($\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (z-1)^n) - 2/(z-1) - (\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-1)^n)$
Is this right? How do I make it look nicer?

For part $(iii)$ I am confused. I have to make the denominator so it is of the form $1-(1/z)$? What do I do with the $1/z$ part of the partial fractions?

So far, for part $(iv)$ I have
($\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (2)^{n} /(z-2)^{n+1})$ - 2($\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n /(z-2)^{n+1}$) + $1/(z-2)$

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate laurent series in the following regions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294035/calculate-laurent-series-in-the-following-regions)

Comment: Why did you asked the same question?

Comment: It was put on hold for not being detailed enough and I didn't understand what that meant so I deleted the old question and asked it again with more details added because before I was very vague what I was asking?